# Possible usage of “wesen”

Tags: meaning

There is a famous aphorism by Heidegger:

> Wie west die Sprache als Sprache? Wir antworten: Die Sprache spricht.

What verb is *west?* Is it likely to be (related to) the low German *wesen?* Or is it a proper high, modern German verb with a meaning significantly different from that of *sein.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb is "wesen" and a High German word. [DWDS considers it obsolete/outdated but still used in elevated/intellectual language](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wesen). Duden [agrees](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wesen). It means "to exist as a living force". Note the meaning of the derivative verb "verwesen" ("to decay/decompose").

Heidegger was Swabian and unlikely to speak Low German.

Comment: And what's more, if anyone nowadays uses _wesen_, they are very likely to talk about Heideggerian philosophy specifically. He tends to have used a lot of Shibboleths like that.

Comment: Also "anwesend" und "abwesend" are related.

Comment: @PaulFrost There are many more related words. Even the Partizip II of "sein" is related. I chose "verwesen" as an example because of how it relates to the meaning of "wesen".